# Add new entries to JavaFX WebEngine history programmatically

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

This might seem strange but i have a specific reason.

> Example

`Mozilla Firefox` allows you when you click the middle mouse button `on the next or previous arrow` from the top url bar , to open a new tab **->** which also remembers the history of the parent tab (the one from which you opened it) .

You can try it to see what i mean.

**Navigate 3-4 sites and then click the middle mouse button on any of the shown arrows**

[image]

> What i have tried

So in JavaFX i have tried to modify the `ObservableList` of `History Object` `WebEngine` , but not luck there cause it is unmodifiable.

Code:

```
webEngine.getHistory(). getHistory().getEntries().add(...) //error
```

I want to implement the same functionality . As for the user interface i know how to do it , it's just this unmodifiable history object that bothers me badly :).

Comment: Hello darkness my friend , i hope to see the light again .... :'''''''(